# is there a jquery remote file upload progress indicator plugin?

Tags: jquery, file-upload, upload

I have an app in which i want to implement a feature where user enters the url of some image file (on remote server e.g. http://www.xyz.com/myimage.jpg) and the file is uploaded to my app server. I can do this through PHP. but i also want to show the progress of the file being uploaded. Is there a JQuery plugin that can do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @SLaks says, you cannot have the client upload a remote file.  However, if you restate your goal as "I want my server to acquire a remote file," you can do that by following these steps:

1. Client sends server the URL to the file.
2. Server *downloads* the remote file from that URL.
3. While the download is taking place, the client polls the server, asking the percent completion of the download.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible.
The client cannot read the remote file.

Instead, you could make a [Comet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comet_%28programming%29) page that read the file in PHP and reports progress to the client as it runs.

Answer (score 0):

It is simply **impossible** to do this. You need to perform the download in a server-side script since JavaScript cannot copy some remote file to your server.

To show a progress bar you need a way such as WebSockets and a server-side language allowing you to handle the download asynchronously (node.js might do the job) to notify the client about the download progress.